# How do I make pyinstaller identify my custom imports?

Tags: python, import, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an exe out of a small Python Project. I have a `main.py` which imports packages from other subdirectories. After building the exe using pyinstaller when I run the executable I am facing import problems, its failing to identify the relative imports.

I tried modifying the .spec file but am unable to rectify the issue.

This is the current directory structure of my project

[Link to project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Irgw.png)

When I run the executable `dist\cli\cli.exe` it gives me this import error

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "cli.py", line 3, in <module>`

`from packages.__main__ import main`

`ImportError: No module named __main__`

`[5964] Failed to execute script cli`

Comment: use hiddenimports in spec file

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota   Thanks , It worked when I tried changing the python version to 3.x (earlier it was picking 2.x). I will also try what you suggested.